# Nurse-scheduling: Largest sequence of no-shifts in N days must be > X

Tags: or-tools

I'm experimenting with the nurse scheduling example, https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling#nurse_scheduling, and trying to figure out how to model the following constraint:

In a sliding 6 week window, each nurse must have at least 14 consecutive days with no shifts (i.e., be assigned to shift `O`).

`add_soft_sequence_constraint` isn't the right tool (I think, if I've understood properly) because that will try and enforce that all sequences of no shifts are 14 days, and I want to enforce that there is at least one sequence of no shifts that is 14 days long.

Any suggestions for how to model this would be gratefully received.

Comment: You could create a boolvar for each 14 day block and apply one AddBoolOr per window